# Where does the mathematical minus sign come from?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C#/.NET library, which works fine in my own environment, but not in a customer's for some reason. In this specific case, .NET Framework 4.8 is used, but they have tried .NET 6 as well with the same results.

I am converting a double with value 0.25 to a string like this:

```
doubleValue.ToString("E16", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In my environment, I get the expected string

```
2.5000000000000000E-001
```

with a hyphen-minus sign (U+002D) in the scientific notation. As seen in the code, I am using InvariantCulture in order to avoid any confusions regarding decimal point signs and minus signs.

In the customer's environment, with the same code they get the string

```
2.5000000000000000E−001
```

with a mathematical minus sign (U+2212) in the scientific notation.

We are both running Windows, with the en-SV culture active. I am printing out the details of InvariantCulture and CurrentCulture in a test program, and in both environments, the negative sign for both cultures is hyphen-minus. Not that current culture *should* affect anything, since I'm explicitly using the InvariantCulture for the conversion.

The customer has tried setting the environment variable DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_USENLS to true, in case there were issues with ICU, but it didn't help. Not that it was likely, since ICU isn't used in .NET Framework. I just couldn't find anything else to try.

What else could affect .NET's choice of minus sign in ToString, apart from culture and NLS/ICU?

EDIT: Additional information: This was not an issue in the previous release of my library. I just released a new version where this became a problem. Since the previous release, I have not touched this conversion code at all. I have added support for .NET 6 (new code that the customer is not running above), and migrated my code from VS2019 to VS2022.

EDIT: Clarified the unicode characters used.

Comment: Because it cannot be seen when looking at your question, the first one is `U+002D`, the second one is `U+2212`, right?

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44678

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I added the Unicode character codes to the original question.  Thank you for input. I know that in some environments the Swedish locale uses the mathematical minus sign from .NET 5 (which is really weird in itself), but the thing is, as stated in the original question, both English and Swedish culture use hyphen-minus in both our environments. PLUS that I follow Microsoft's guidelines according to your link, of using InvariantCulture in the conversion. PLUS that we are running .NET Framework.

Comment: How is the customer providing you with the text? Is it possible that actually your code is outputting U+002D, but some copy/paste operation is modifying it? Can you log the precise characters as a separate operation? What happens if you log `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign`? Do the customer see the same issue for simple negative values, e.g. -5?

Comment: I have a test program that we are both running which is doing Console.WriteLine(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NegativeSign), which indicates U+002D everywhere. The test program is also using Console.WriteLine to output the string, where the sign is U+2212 instead. They are copy-pasting it to us. I know it is not a copy-paste issue, since the issue I'm trying to solve for them is that code that was previously working (where we interpret the string) now throws an InvalidFormatException.

Comment: I can't reproduce this even with customized regional settings. Consider asking for the result of `BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(0.01d.ToString("E16", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))`, which will not be subject to any transformation issues outside the program itself.